# How to determine linear independence for polynomial?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

Determine if the following is dependent or independent:

In $P_3$:

$P_1 (x)=1$

$P_2 (x)=(1+x)$

$P_3 (x)=(1+x)^2$

$P_4 (x)=(1+x)^3$

I used the Wronskian method:

```
1    1+x       x^2 +2x+1    x^3 +3x^2 +3x+1
0     1         2x+2         3x^2 +6x+3
0     0          2             6x+6
0     0          0              6
```

is this correct?

Comment: Looks good. Now notice the determinant of a triangular matrix is the product of the diagonal entries. An easier approach: suppose $c_1+c_2(1+x)+c_3(1+x)^2+c_4(1+x)^3=0$. For this to have no $x^3$ term, it must have $c_4=0$. Now to have no $x^2$ term you need $c_3=0$. And so on. This exploits the (easier-to-prove) fact that the monomials are linearly independent.

Answer (score 1):

Wronskians aren't really necessary for this problem. Start by arranging all the coefficients of your polynomials into a matrix, like so:

$$\left[\begin{matrix}
  1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
  0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
  0 & 0 & 1 & 3 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 \end{matrix}\right]$$

(Each column corresponds to one of your polynomials.)

Now use basic linear algebra to conclude that the columns of this matrix are linearly independent. It follows that your polynomials are, too.

Following this line of thought, it seems to be a general principle that if $R$ is a commutative domain and $p \in R[x]$ is a non-constant polynomial, then the set $\{p^0,p^1,p^2,\ldots\}$ is always linearly independent over $R$. Note that this set is definitely not linearly independent over $R[x]$, though!

Answer (score 0):

A hint:

Use the following principle: An ordered set of vectors $x_k$ $(1\leq k\leq r)$ is linearly dependent iff one of the $x_k$ is a linear combination of its predecessors.